# Ideal behavior for a constraint in online test c#

Tags: c#

I want to know how to proceed if a console input is not met in a online test.

Like - 0 > x > 10

Sample question -

Please take two inputs from user and return the sum of the both.

Constraint -

```
         0 < a < 10

         2 < b <= 15
```

Below are solutions I have tried with their success rate.

- Case 1:

  ```
      int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      while (a < 1 || a > 9)
          a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

      int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      while (b < 3 || b > 15)
          b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  ```

Success - 35 %

- Case 2

  ```
  int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  if(a < 1 || a > 9)
     Environment.Exit(0);

  int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  if(b < 3 || b > 15)
     Environment.Exit(0);
  ```

Success - 35 %

- Case 3:

  ```
      try
      {
          int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
          if (a < 1 || a > 9)
              throw new ArgumentException();

          int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
          if (b < 3 || b > 15)
              throw new ArgumentException();

          return a + b;
      }
      catch(ArgumentException ex)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(ex);
      }
  ```

Success - 0%

- Case 4: Without Constraint

  ```
  int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  return a + b;
  ```

Success - 95%

So what am I missing to get 100%

Comment: What is the actual objective of the online test?

Comment: There is a logic to implement based on input and print the output to the console. There are constraints mentioned for input. It does not show the test cases but it shows the success percentage.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide the **full question** and a [mcve] of your progress so far on the implementation.

Comment: I have provided a sample question to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do a validation of some sort. Don't use an "Environment.Exit" because a while loop doesn't work like that. A while loop will continue until it returns "False" for example see the code below to validate digit input in the console.

```
while(!int.TryParse(someString, out int someInt))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Your variable someString contains something other than numbers.");
}
```

Your code might look something like this.0 > x > 10

```
while(x < 0 || x > 10)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Do this code.");
}
```

Constraints:

```
 0 < a < 10

 2 < b <= 15
```

Code:

```
int a;
int b; //Declare these outside the loop.

while(!(a > 0 && a < 10 && b > 2 && b <=15))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Please Input a valid number for A.");
   a = Console.ReadLine();
   Console.WriteLine("Please Input a valid number for B.";
   b = Console.ReadLine();
}

int sum = a + b;

Console.WriteLine($"The sum is {sum}.");
```

Comment: Keep in mind this while loop will continue until it returns "True" because of the "!" (Not) operator.

Comment: I have done same... So it shows success percentage as 95%

Comment: Please add more info to your initial post, screenshot, or anything really. Your initial post is very vague.

Comment: I just wanted to know for these online test portals what should be the ideal steps to handle the invalid input. There is nothing mentioned in the details as well

Comment: The best way to handle an invalid input is definitely a While loop so that you can re-prompt the user for the input. The problem we're having is we don't understand your question entirely.

Comment: @MathewKaulfers I have added a sample code and code submissions with success rate.

Comment: Give me just a sec. I have your solution now.